# ctools_ajax_command_redirect is no longer working to redirect ajax form on successful submit

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, redirection

My ajax callback function which is changing a form did redirect properly in the past, but now with no change to this code it does not work anymore.

```
function node_create_callback($form, &$form_state){
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    node_form_validate($form, $form_state);
    if (!form_get_errors()){

      //on success submit form and redirect
      node_form_submit($form,$form_state);
      ctools_include('ajax');
      ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
      $commands =  array(ctools_ajax_command_redirect("node/"));
      return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
    }
    else
    {
      //on error display errors on form without refreshing page
      $commands = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#error' => FALSE, '#commands' => array());
      $output = drupal_render($form);
      $commands['#commands'][] = ajax_command_insert(NULL, $output);
      // Prepend status messages to the node form.
      $commands['#commands'][] = ajax_command_prepend(NULL, theme('status_messages'));
      return $commands;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

> return array('#type' => 'ajax',  '#commands' => $commands);

try this

> print ajax_render($commands);
>
> drupal_exit();

I had a similar problem, and this code worked for me.

courtesy: [Ajax redirect on successful submission is not working properly](https://drupal.org/node/2030561#comment-7606451)

Hope that helps!